# Google Chrome icon disappears from app tray after restarting?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-experience

I have installed the Google Experience Launcher on my Nexus 7, and have a variety of applications in my app tray, including Google Chrome. However, each time I power off and power on the device, Google Chrome disappears from my app tray;

[image]

I can re-add it fine and it will stay present until the next time I power off the device. What is causing this problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Could it be you've installed Chrome on your internal `/sdcard` partition? That's the most common reason for "disappearing icons/widgets", as the launcher gets started while the SDCard is not yet fully mounted (both, launcher and mounting process, get started almost simultaneously, so the latter might not be finished in time).

Comment: I wasn't given an option to choose where applications were installed - also, this problem doesn't occur in other launchers

Comment: Does it show up under *hidden apps*? But @Izzy is correct in the first comment.

Comment: Go to Applications under Settings, and see if you can move Chrome to the primary storage.  There is no prompt, and how other launchers behave doesn't affect the fact that the primary launcher is a silly thing that removes shortcuts if it can't find the app.

Answer (score 0):

That happens on Stock "***Launcher***" sometimes, and I don't think that there's anything you can do until Google, or the manufacturer releases an update. Until then you can use a different launcher if it really bothers you. Personally, I use Next Launcher 3D and nothing else. Izzy's response seems most feasible to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the *Google Now Launcher* and *Chrome* app caches in *Settings › Applications*. Since an app's configuration sometimes is also stored in it's cache, clearing those caches should *fingers crossed*, force the apps to rewrite your config to their caches and allow the icon to survive through reboots.

Comment: all set and yea the n7 had two storage size models; 16gb & 32gb.

Comment: I've just cleaned up the post a little (and no, the down-votes are not mine): The SD card IMHO has nothing to do with the issue (it *might* have if the "icon" were a *widget*), so it looked a bit confusing – especially as it appeared to say installing the app on SD card would help (if it were related, it would rather be the other way around – see my comment on the question itself).

Comment: ok, i think i misunderstood what you wanted in the edit. all good. thanks for the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Google Play Store app, and search for Chrome. Which buttons show up on the app page? Do you see "Open" and "Uninstall"? Is there an "Enable" button? If you see "Enable," then it's been disabled somehow. I know you mentioned looking to see if it was disabled, but just to be sure--go to Settings>Apps>All, and tell us where you see Chrome. Is it where it should be in alphabetical order? Or is it at the very bottom of the list?

If it isn't disabled, then you could try the following, but be aware that it will reset your homescreens and make them blank, such that you'll have to set them up again. Go to Settings>Apps>All, select "Launcher" (or possibly "Homescreen"), and Clear Data. I think the App Drawer is part of the Launcher, so perhaps by clearing data, it will force the Launcher to repopulate the App Drawer, and maybe Chrome will then show up.